# W11: RegEdit Permission Errors & Uninstalling BootCamp Drivers

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, boot-camp

Unsuccessfully been trying to get my Magic Keyboard fn keys working (via Brigadier/.inf files) on my ASUS Windows 11 laptop.

I have unfortunately installed several drivers via Brigadier and this [directory](https://github.com/AbsentForeskin/Apple-Input-Device-Drivers-Windows-10-11).. I have uninstalled BootCamp via BootCamp.msi, but several drivers (?) still remain in the RegEdit, and I cannot remove them.

[Multiple drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajMcE.png)

[Error when deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X5dg.png)

[Full Control permissions but not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RzeG.png)

Comment: Just removing those registry keys won't remove the drivers.  Your screenshots suggest that the user you are using does NOT have permission to those keys, which makes sense considering they are under HKLM